# Procedural Textures in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, texture2d, procedural-generation

I am mainly a programmer, not very good at drawing, so I decided to make textures at run time in a procedural way and by that I mean to generate something new and fresh every time at the same time it should look believable.How to get Started with this ? Programming in Unity, if that is going to help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create Textures in code by doing something like this:

```
public Texture2D CreateTexture()
{
    int width = 100;
    int height = 100;

    texture = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
    texture.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            texture.SetPixel(j, Height-1-i, Color.red);
        }
    }
    texture.Apply();
    return texture;
}
```

You may want to look into [Texture2D.SetPixels()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixels.html) if you are looking to optimize, as [Texture2D.SetPixel()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixel.html) is much slower.

For the procedural texture generation, that is a very broad topic, with various techniques.  Typically, you would use some sort of coherent noise generator to generate your textures, such as Perlin or Simplex.

You can google "Texture Generation Noise", and find a wide range of articles explaining how to do this.

This question is really broad, so hope that helps you get started.

Comment: I meant more like algorithms for generation @Jon